# Array values set as combobox value

Tags: javascript, php

I am hardly trying to this code successful. Below is my php array code from other page and i retrieved all values that corresponds to my `$query`

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $a[]= $row['addons_name'];              

        }
        $kk= 0;
            for($x=0;$x<$count-1;$x++)
            {

                $kk = $a[$x];
                echo $kk;

            }
```

my problem is I want the values of `$kk` to be the value of my combobox using JavaScript here is my code

```
var select = document.getElementById("combobox");
for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++ ) {
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(data[index], index);
}
```

data = echo value which is `$kk`.
the output of the cobobox is character which is supposedly should be a word
i want have an output like "egg" instead of
e
g
g
please help

Comment: what is `data` in your javascript ?

Comment: data is value i echo in php which is $kk

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code,

```
$kk= 0;
for($x=0;$x<$count-1;$x++)
{
    $kk = $a[$x];
    echo $kk;
}
```

to

```
$to_echo_in_javascript = json_encode($a);
```

It simply converts `php` variables to `javascript` understandable variables, without applying our own logic.

then, use it in javascript, like,

```
data = <?php echo $to_echo_in_javascript; ?>;
```

Other your code is good. Here is snippet sample, Click run, to see in effect.

```js
var data = [1,2,3,'viral','anything']; // php variables will be here after rendering

var select = document.getElementById("combobox");
for(var index = 0; index < data.length; index++ ) {
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(index, data[index]);
}
```

```html
<select id='combobox'>
    <option value='0'>default value 1</option>
    <option value='0'>default value 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I wanted data to be the value of cobobox

Comment: I mean the output of data is "mimi" "output" input" those are 3 words but the output is the value of the combobox is the character of the words
(m
i
m
i). I think the  value of data will become one word when it appear in javascript *take note my array is from other page*.